# How to get selected value from DevExpress LookupEdit?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

Hai all,
       Am using DevExpress LookupEdit in C#.NET project,also set both Display Member and Value member property of LookupEdit.How do I get selected value from DevExpress LookupEdit.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the lookupEdit.EditValue property.  If you need to obtain the editor's DisplayText, use its Text property.